# Best way to dynamically update non-static data in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a `RecyclerView` that stores items from an `API`. The problem is that the objects returned from the API shift around based on users interacting with them.

So let's take an example, let's say I make a request to the API to grab a list like so:

```
{
   "startTime": "2016-02-01 01:20:60",
   "endTime": "2016-02-01 01:00:60",
   "objects": [
   {
    "id": "4",
    "image": "http://image.com/1",
    "type": "image"
   },
   {
    "id": "3",
    "text": "Something something",
    "type": "post"
   },
   {
    "id": "2",
    "text": "Something else",
    "type": "post"
   },
   {
    "id": "1",
    "text": "Something",
    "type": "post"
   }
   ]
}
```

Ok that's stored in the list, **NOW** the users hits `SwipeToRefresh` and this is returned back from the API:

```
{
   "startTime": "2016-02-01 01:30:60",
   "endTime": "2016-02-01 01:20:60",
   "objects": [
   {
    "id": "8",
    "image": "http://image.com/10",
    "type": "image"
   },
   {
    "id": "7",
    "text": "Something new",
    "type": "post"
   },
   {
    "id": "3",
    "text": "Something something",
    "type": "post"
   },
   {
    "id": "4",
    "text": "Something something",
    "type": "post"
   }
   ]
}
```

Notice that `Posts` with `id`s of **3** and **4** are returned back in a new list! We need to somehow remove the older items and update the list with these items gracefully.

What is a good design to implement this? Is there anything clean and robust?

My initial hunch would be to:

```
adapter.update(List<Object> newObjects);

// Later on in adapter...

void update(List<Object> newObjects) {

    // Add items to the top of the list

    // Sort through old list and if ids match newer items remove them
    loop {
        // Call notifyItemRemoved
    }
}
```

Any better thoughts on this? By good design I mean updating the list without the user taking notice of any jankiness or lag.

**Please read the question carefully before downvoting or answering, this may sound like a simple question. It's not.**:

Specifically I am looking for answers that deal with effective memory allocation, a simple clean fluid interface and easily debuggable.

An ideal solution would probably be a base 'abstract' 'RecyclerViw.Adapter' that holds the logic for updating / removing / modifying a 'ViewHolder' with thread safety. Assume I am already using libraries to handle JSON / POJO serialization and Client-side REST.

**The items in my RecyclerView get shifted around in a list reflected from the list returned from the API. Items move around and are dynamic when the user is refreshing the view from the top or loading more views from the bottom when scrolling down. Items are not static in a list their positions will change depending on users interacting with those items as reflecting from the list returned from API.**

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I know that there is a basic answer for this which is what I listed above, but I am looking for a more polished answer since my app handles complex data and dynamic views.

Comment: You should keep the ids the same and add a lastUpdated timestamp to your data

Comment: Seems like a legit question, upvoted you back to zero

Answer (score 1):

If you want nice and fluid design, I would create a Sqlite Database for your app. Store the data in Database that you get from the web api call. Every time user swipes down for new data then parse JSON and update the database. Do this using AsyncTask, service or IntentService in the background thread and not on Main(UI) thread.

Now hook up your RecyclerView with your stored items in the database using CursorLoaders. Of course you would have to do a little more work this way but it would be worth it at the end.

hope this would be a good starting point.

Comment: Seems a bit more intensive than just holding an LruCache?

Comment: Also this doesn't address the Question at all

Comment: actually, I think it does answer the question. you're looking for a way to update the view easily, right? with Bhavik's answer, you get the update by just passing in the new cursor for the data.

Comment: Yes but I believe OP also wants a solution where by items being updated try their best to maintain their original position in the list....so that the user doesn't see it jumping around.

Answer (score 0):

I would use retrofit for getting my objects from api, then I would create a Gson model for the object returned by your api. Something like:

```
class Model{
    private String startTime;
    private String endTime;
    private Post[] objects;
    class Post{
       private String id;
       private String text;
       private String type;
       // get/set methods
    }

    // get/set methods
}
```

And then I will use rxAndroid for modifying my list.

[See here on how to use rx with retrofit](https://medium.com/@ahmedrizwan/rxandroid-and-retrofit-2-0-66dc52725fff#.uvijknyb7). I would suggest studying flatmap of rxjava for parsing your objects in `Post[]`. I'm not an expert in rx so I can't give an example yet.

Comment: This is totally unrelated to my question.

Comment: @AndyRoid is updating list using rx not related?

Comment: @AndyRoid Correct me if I'm wrong, but your question is a nice method on how to update recyclerview for every api call, right?

Comment: Nope my question is related to updating a dynamic list, the items in the list shift around

Comment: ah. so the items swaps positions.

Comment: Yes! Swapping around! I have a brute force implementation in mind. Something like 'seeIfItemShouldBeUpdated(Model model);' which would go and see if the item already exists in the list and swap it. But maybe there is a better way?